# how to round off float after two place decimal in c or c++

Tags: c++, c++11, floating-point, rounding, precision

how to round off float value after two place decimal in c or c++

examples:

1. let input is `95.346789` so output is `95.35`
2. let input `95.345` output is `95.35`
3. let input `95.344` output is `95.34`

Comment: Just: `round(f * 100) / 100`

Comment: Do you really need to round it (if yes, why?), or just to display it rounded?

Comment: Avoid floats if you can. You actually can't do what you ask because 100.01 can't be represented using float. If possible do your calculation using integers.

Comment: @DimChtz If you have an answer and the question is not off-topic/duplicate consider posting as an answer.

Comment: You can't, because floating point doesn't have decimal places. It has binary places, and they are incommensurable with decimal places.

Comment: @EJP: Neither C nor C++ mandates binary floating-point. The radix is implementation-defined. Further, while one cannot exactly represent numbers such as 95.35 in binary floating-point, one can round to two decimal digits by delivering the result in another format, such as the string format delivered by `snprintf`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil 1. Can you cite an implementation that doesn't use binary radix? 2. 'Another format' is not sufficient. It needs to be a decimal radix.

Comment: @EJP: 1. I did not say there are implementations that do not use binary floating-point. There are implementations that do support decimal floating-point. (In other words, the fact that an implementation does support decimal floating-point does not mean it does not support binary floating-point.) Both [Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-decimal-floating-point-with-intel-c-compiler) and [IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxbd00/ieeedecint.htm) offer decimal floating-point hardware and software.

Comment: @EJP: 2. So? Every conforming C implementation provides conversions to and from decimal.

Comment: Hallo *@Naveen satyarthi*, the accepted answer is not correct, even it is working for you. Therefore, could you **unaccept** it, by **un-ticking** the right arrow next to it.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Something like as follows. Hope that its understandable. 
Output:https://www.ideone.com/EnP40j

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
   float num1 = 95.345f;
   float num2 = 95.344f;

   num1 = roundf(num1 * 100) / 100; //rounding two decimals
   num2 = roundf(num2 * 100) / 100; //rounding two decimals

   std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed
             << num1 << " " << num2 << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @JeJo No. The issue is the same regardless of what language. The question is ill-formed, regardless of the programming language, for the reason stated in my comment, which is not language-specific.

Comment: The code in this answer is not correct because multiplying by 100 induces rounding errors when the floating-point arithmetic is not decimal-based, and so does dividing by 100. A proper way to convert to two decimal digits is to use the formatting operations (such as C’s `snprintf` or C++’s insertion operators) with suitable format specifications. However, even this requires that the implementation format correctly, which the C and C++ standards do not completely guarantee. Barring a trustworthy implementation, extended-precision techniques must be used.

Answer (score 0):

In C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    float num;
    char buf[10];
    printf("Enter float value: ");
    fgets(buf, 10, stdin);
    sscanf(buf, "%lf", &num):
    num = (roundf(num * 100.0) / 100.0);
    printf(num = %.2f\n", num);
}
```

Comment: The code in this answer is not correct because multiplying by 100 induces rounding errors when the floating-point arithmetic is not decimal-based, and so does dividing by 100. A proper way to convert to two decimal digits is to use the formatting operations (such as C’s `snprintf` or C++’s insertion operators) with suitable format specifications. However, even this requires that the implementation format correctly, which the C and C++ standards do not completely guarantee. Barring a trustworthy implementation, extended-precision techniques must be used.